# 動的に生成したチェックBOXに対して、チェックしたチェックBOX以外のチェックを外したい

Tags: wpf

WPFにて動的にタブを生成し、そのタブ内にそれぞれ１つずつチェックBOXを生成する画面を作っています。
チェックを入れたチェックBOX以外のチェックを外したいのですが、”IsChecked”を使うコントロール(以下ソースのｘｘｘ)に何を指定すればよいのかわからず、困っています。
アドバイスお願い致します。

＜補足＞
　VS2010、.net4.0の環境です。

```
private void Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   // チェックイベント処理
    System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox chkObj = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)sender;

    for (タブ数分ループする)
    {
        // 全てのチェックBOXからチェックを外す処理を入れたい
        ｘｘｘ.IsChecked = false;      // ”ｘｘｘ”になにを入れればよいのかがわかりません。
    }
    chkObj.IsChecked = true;            // チェック操作したチェックBOXにチェックを入れる
}
```

＜XAML抜粋＞

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl" Margin="50,15,0,15" ItemsSource="{Binding TabPanels}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding TabButtons}" Margin="{Binding TabCtrlMg}">
                    ～～～中略～～～
                </ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding TabCk}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Checked="Checked" Unchecked="UnChecked" HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:DataContext="{Binding CheckKey}">
                                <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="3" ScaleY="3"/>
                                </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="35,0,0,5"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: この記事とか参考になるかもしれません。[How to Loop Through CheckBoxes in a TabControl using WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39982806/9014308), [LogicalTreeHelper Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.logicaltreehelper?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0) あるいはこちらが何かのヒントになるかも。[WPF C# accessing a checkbox in a custom Tabitem control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38516801/9014308)